# HiveError (HiveError: Cannot read, unknown typeId: 33. Did you forget to register an adapter?)

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive, flame

I'm setting up Hive in my flutter flame game and getting typeId 33 is not found error.
I tried deleting Hive from the directory, flutter project cache clean & rebuild, redownloading and upgrading all pacakges.
I've tried all solutions on the internet, but it still does not work.
I think I'm getting this error when getting a box... because it says it cannot find the adapter.

here are the code files -->

plyaer_data.dart file:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part 'player_data.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class PlayerData extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  int health = 0;
  @HiveField(1)
  int itemsCollected = 0;
  @HiveField(2)
  int totalItemsNum = 0;
  @HiveField(3)
  bool isOkToNextFloor = false;
  @HiveField(4)
  bool showControls = false; 
  @HiveField(5)
  bool isSoundEffectOn = true;
  @HiveField(6)
  bool isMusicOn = true;
  @HiveField(7)
  double soundEffectVolume = 1.0;
  @HiveField(8)
  double musicVolume = 1.0;
  @HiveField(9)
  int currentFloorIndex = 0;
}
```

player_data.g.dart file:

```
part of 'player_data.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class PlayerDataAdapter extends TypeAdapter<PlayerData> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  PlayerData read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return PlayerData()
      ..health = fields[0] as int
      ..itemsCollected = fields[1] as int
      ..totalItemsNum = fields[2] as int
      ..isOkToNextFloor = fields[3] as bool
      ..showControls = fields[4] as bool
      ..isSoundEffectOn = fields[5] as bool
      ..isMusicOn = fields[6] as bool
      ..soundEffectVolume = fields[7] as double
      ..musicVolume = fields[8] as double
      ..currentFloorIndex = fields[9] as int;
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, PlayerData obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(10)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.health)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.itemsCollected)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.totalItemsNum)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.isOkToNextFloor)
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..write(obj.showControls)
      ..writeByte(5)
      ..write(obj.isSoundEffectOn)
      ..writeByte(6)
      ..write(obj.isMusicOn)
      ..writeByte(7)
      ..write(obj.soundEffectVolume)
      ..writeByte(8)
      ..write(obj.musicVolume)
      ..writeByte(9)
      ..write(obj.currentFloorIndex);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is PlayerDataAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

main.dart file:

```
PlayerData playerData = PlayerData();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Flame.device.fullScreen();
  await Flame.device.setLandscape();
  runApp(const MyApp());

  if (playerData.isMusicOn) {
    FlameAudio.bgm.play('main-menu-music.mp3', volume: playerData.musicVolume);
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.pressStart2pTextTheme(),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder<PlayerData>(
        initialData: PlayerData(),
        future: getGameData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else {
            return const MainMenu();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> initHive() async {
  final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(dir.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter<PlayerData>(PlayerDataAdapter());
}

Future<PlayerData> getGameData() async {
  await initHive();
  final box = await Hive.openBox<PlayerData>('PlayerDataBox');
  final gameData = box.get('PlayerData');

  if (gameData == null) {
    box.put('PlayerData', PlayerData());
  }
  return box.get('PlayerData')!;
}
```